# Running Elastic Local in CLuster Mode

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am running Elastic in Local mode. That is to say, Elastic is running in the same JVM as my process. So the concept of Node and Client is not their.

Elastic is able to create and read the indexes it it creating on my local directory. 
I wish to have multiple instances of Elastic each one in local mode but in cluster mode. I.e. Each will have its own data directory but the data will be replicated and the nodes will be in cluster.

I tried with two processes on same machine, but each one of them is running as master node and not going into the cluster.

Can you possibly help.

Comment: Both of them are running as data node. But both are not going into the cluster. One is running from Eclipse IDE. Another from the command prompt. It si being executed on Windows. Both are running as their own master. Cluster name for both of them are same. Node name is different.  HTTP mode is disabled for both of them.